# Device tree syntax for how to enable pull up on GPIO line in overlay device tree source for TI AM33XX SoC

Tags: linux, device-tree

Please advise me on device tree syntax (dts file and/or dtsi file syntax) to enable by default a PIN INPUT PULLUP setting for GPIO lines on AM33XX SoC TI chip? Even enabling the pull ups on all GPIO pins in a particular bank would be fine.

I have NOT seen any syntax/documentation in the device tree bindings about this:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/linux-yocto-4.4/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings?h=standard/beaglebone

From am33xx.dtsi file
Device Tree Source for AM33XX SoC:

```
gpio0: gpio@44e07000 {
        compatible = "ti,omap4-gpio";
        ti,hwmods = "gpio1";
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <2>;
        reg = <0x44e07000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <96>;
    };
```

**The following are files I can change:**

From my platform common.dtsi file (overlay on top of am33xx in my kernel source)
linux-yocto_4.4/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-_common.dtsi

#enabling this uio line and it will be assigned to an GPIO line

```
 uio13: uio_pdrv_genirq@13 {
    compatible = "uio,pdrv_genirq";
    status = "disabled";
};

#turn on all GPIO lines in bank 0
&gpio0 {
  ti,gpio-always-on;
};
```

From my platform dts file (overlay on top of am33xx in my kernel source and using common.dtsi file)

linux-yocto_4.4/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-.dts

```
&uio13 {
irq-gpio = <20>;        /* GPIO 20 in bank 0 */
irq-trigger = <0x3>;    /* trigger rising|falling */
status = "okay";
};
```